# Finding Tension in cable in 3D Equilibrium

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics, moments

In a typical 3D Equilibrium problem.

Assume you have two cables points supporting a mass. The two cables are K distance above origin and form a quadratic triangle with the mass which is a the same distance K from origin but in + y axis. A strut from origin interest the two cables at mass.

My question is. To find tension in two cables, do I need to find moment about origin or do I just need to equate the I,j and k components of the two tension forces to zero and solve then using Cramer's rule?

When do I need moment to find tension? When don't I need it?

Comment: Please rephrase your question to make it clear as to what you say and add a diagram.

Comment: In general for problems like this you consider them 'catenary' and you must find equilibrium in the displaced state in order to find the the solution.